# Searching a list for occurrences of specific characters

Tags: python, regex, list, match

I'm attempting to search through a list to find any occurrence of two numbers back to back.

```
import re
list1 = ["something10", "thing01", "thingy05"]
list2 = re.findall(re.match([0-1][0-9]), list1)
```

Whenever I try the above in Python command line, I get the following error.

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

What does this error mean, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`re.findall` takes a pattern (or a compiled RE) as the first arg, a string as the second arg.  You're failing at **both**!-)

`re.match` returns a match object or `None` -- neither is acceptable as an argument to `re.findall`!  Just pass the `r'[0-1][0-9]'` pattern there.

The second arg needs to be a string, not a list, so, use a loop...:

```
list2 = []
for astring in list1:
    list2.extend(re.findall(r'[0-1][0-9]', astring))
```